# Why is Round Nearest Ties Away Rounding mode optional in the IEEE754 standard for Binary formats?

Tags: floating-point, rounding, ieee-754

As Quoted from IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (2008) Section 4.3.3

> An implementation of this standard shall provide roundTiesToEven and the three directed rounding attributes. A decimal format implementation of this standard shall provide roundTiesToAway as a user- selectable rounding-direction attribute. The rounding attribute roundTiesToAway is not required for a binary format implementation.

I understand the bias of tie breaking using round away. I am just curious as to the reasoning why tie-breaking for rounding away is optional for binary and required for decimal.

Comment: I cannot speak authoritatively (hence a comment and not an answer) without reviewing committee discussion, but I suspect it is because it is new, and the committee did not judge its burden to be worth imposing on manufacturers. Also, it differs from the others in that its primary purpose is to retain some information for further rounding rather than to directly provide a mathematically desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah I figured only members of that reviewing committee would be able to answer definitely, but your guess makes sense. I didn't think of industry when thinking about why. I thought that sentence may have been added to signify a difference in mathematical properties of round away between binary / decimal formats (which did not make sense to me hence the question).

Comment: Well, I was on the committee back then, but that does not mean I remember anything from it. A lot has happened since then.

Comment: Generally, a feature could be optional in a standard when there exists previous technology that does not implement the feature while the committee would like that technology to be deemed conforming. Of course other reason could apply, like if there are possible trade-offs implementing it.

Comment: @Arma6815 May be useful: the other day I was wondering "[why conversion from real floating to integer requires that the value is truncated toward zero (and not, for example,  rounds to nearest)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69034886/1778275)".

Answer (score 1):

roundTiesToAway is also called commercial rounding.

Muller et al.: "Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic" explains:

roundTiesToAway is useful for some accounting calculations. This is why it is required for radix-10 implementations only, the main use of radix 10 being financial calculations. For instance, the European Council Regulation No. 1103/97 of 17 June 1997 on certain provisions relating to the introduction
of the Euro sets out a number of rounding and conversion rules. Among them,
If the application of the conversion rate gives a result which is exactly half-way, the sum shall be rounded up.

X86 and ARM microprocessors only have 2 bits in the control word for setting rounding mode. They don't have space for adding a 5th rounding mode. That's a reason for not making roundTiesToAway mandatory for binary floating point representations.